# refreshView for Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning, aura, lightning-web-components, refresh, viewstate

Whats the lwc equivalent of this aura event?

> $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue myself today as well. In my case, I had a Quick Action Lightning Aura Component which enveloped a Lightning Web Component (because there is currently no way of using a Lightning Web Component as a Quick Action)..

What I did is set up my Aura Component to catch 'close' events:

```
<!-- aura/auraComponent/auraComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
    <c:webComponent recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.handleClose}" />
</aura:component>
```

And process them with the events I would LIKE to throw from my Web Component:

```
// aura/auraComponent/auraComponentController.js
({
    handleClose: function() {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

And in my Web Component I throw the following Custom Event to trigger the refresh & quick action close:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
```

I know it's ugly, but at the time of writing I don't think there's a better way to refresh an underlying record page & close a Quick Action modal from a Lightning Web Component.

Comment: I have copied your code. closeQuickAction works, but not refreshView. I have tried single quotes and double quotes (you mixed them), but that does not make any difference. Does the refresh update the related lists in your case?

Comment: No, actually - it refreshes my record detail page but not the related lists. It might be to do with this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDOuQAM

Answer (score 4):

Starting in [Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm), you'll be able to use `getRecordNotifyChange()` function to refresh your record page from a lightning web component.

`getRecordNotifyChange` is working almost the same way `force:refreshView` did, except it takes a list of `recordId` which makes it a little bit more flexible:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import apexUpdateRecord from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.apexUpdateRecord';
     
export default class NotifyRecordChangeExample extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
     
  // Wire a record.
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ... })
  record;
     
  async handler() {
    // Update the record via Apex.
    await apexUpdateRecord(this.recordId);
    // Notify LDS that you've changed the record outside its mechanisms.
    getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
  }
}
```

Comment: getRecordNotifyChange only works for LDS data right? and I tried this it was not working for refreshing stale LDS cache data.

Comment: It's for LDS right, if you pass a record Id it should refresh this record's cache.

Comment: Thanks @FabienTaillon, working like a charm, could you please explain why do we need to wire a method additionally, without below code it's not working.
// Wire a record.
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ... })
  record;

Answer (score -1):

call the refreshApex () method if you want to get result from the SF

```
import apexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/Namespace.Classname.apexMethod';
@wire(apexMethod, { apexMethodParams })
propertyOrFunction;

    // opportunitiesOverAmount.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getOpptyOverAmount from '@salesforce/apex/OpptiesOverAmountApex.getOpptyOverAmount';
import updateOpptyStage from '@salesforce/apex/OpptiesOverAmountApex.updateOpptyStage';

export default class OpportunitiesOverAmount extends LightningElement {
    @api amount;

    @wire(getOpptyOverAmount, { amount: '$amount' })
    opptiesOverAmount;

    handleClick(e) {
        updateOpptyStage({
            stage: 'Won'
        })
        .then(() => {
            return refreshApex(this.opptiesOverAmount);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.message = 'Error received: code' + error.errorCode + ', ' +
                'message ' + error.body.message;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps updating the value of `@wire` property. But `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` is used to tell OTHER components that things need to refresh.

Comment: Yes that is correct @zaitsman, I need to tell other components that things need to be refreshed.